# How to get Edit Text (string) from individual card in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a recyclerview. Each card has an edit text where I need to input a string. I have a button which pushes these values (one on each card) to push these values to a database, but I'm not sure how to get these values individually.

**Adapter Class**

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;

ArrayList<posts> list;




public PostsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<posts> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.posts,parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    posts posts = list.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(posts.getTitle());
    holder.level.setText(posts.getSubject());
    holder.lang.setText(posts.getSec());
    holder.desc.setText(posts.getDesc());
    holder.author.setText(posts.getAuthor());

    boolean isVisible = posts.visibility;
    holder.constraintLayout.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return list.size();

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title, level, lang, desc, author;

    CardView posts1;
    LinearLayout constraintLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleposts);
        level = itemView.findViewById(R.id.level);
        lang = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lang);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descposts);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandedlayout);

        title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                posts posts = list.get(getAdapterPosition());
                posts.setVisibility(!posts.isVisibility());
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });



    }


}}
```

I've tried looking at other stackoverflow replies, but i still don't get it

Comment: Please remove the bold. Dont shout.